# How much communication is -really- verbal?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, communication

It is often said that only a small part of our daily communication is through words, sometimes accompanied with claims that X% is through words, Y% through body language, Z% facial expressions, etc.

However, several studies show that introverts and extroverts communicate differently.

- Several studies show that introverts are more precise and effective at giving information with their communication.
- At least 1 study shows that extroverts use more body language than introverts.
- At least 1 study shows that extroverts use more eye-contact than introverts.

Based on this I am certain that communication style can be used as a cue to personality traits.
**So I'm looking for studies that could tell me several correlations on this at the same time. A study that can tell me correlations like these:**

- The correlation between Big 5 traits and communication through body language?
- The correlation between Big 5 traits and communication through eye contact?
- The correlation between Big 5 traits and verbal communication?
- The correlation between Big 5 traits and tone of voice/vocal pitch?

**References**

- Taking care of the linguistic features of extraversion, Gill & Oberlander, 2002
- Personality, sex and computer-mediated communication through the internet,  http://www.ub.edu/personal/jgutierrez/cmc.pdf)
  http://jls.sagepub.com/content/32/2/191
- The Language of Extraversion: Extraverted People Talk More Abstractly, Introverts Are More Concrete, http://epublications.uef.fi/pub/urn_nbn_fi_uef-20140646/urn_nbn_fi_uef-20140646.pdf
- Yuichi Iizuka (1992) Eextraversion, introversion, and visual interaction. Perceptual and Motor Skills: Volume 74, Issue , pp. 43-50.